# ruby - add Enumerable functionality and more to a class

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I want to give all of those ruby treats to my class (working on an underlying data structure). `include Enumarable` only does part of the job.
What's the best way?

```
class A
    def initialize
        @data = 10.times.map { |e| e }
    end

    include Enumerable
    def each(&block)
        @data.each(&block)
    end
end

#works great
A.new.each {}
A.new.select {|e| e > 3}
A.new.reject {|e| e > 3}
A.new.partition {|e| e > 3}
A.new.count

# those will fail
A.new.size
A.new.length
A.new.select! {|e| e > 3}
```

Comment: except from enumerable functionality, what else does your class need to do? Because simple inheritance from `Array` could possibly do the job.

Comment: tip: `#size` and `#length` are not defined on `Enumerable`, but  `A.new.count` works.

Comment: @xlembouras interesting. care to elaborate?

Comment: there are various types of mixins in the ruby library, you can use them too..see this link
http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html

Answer (score 3):

`size`, `length` and all the methods that mutate the collection in place, like `select!`, are not part of `Enumerable`.

If you want them you must implement them yourself.

Comment: yea, there are not a part of ```Enumarable``` , hence my question. waiting for some ruby magic here. tnx

Comment: There is no ruby magic, either you implement them yourself for your data structure or you inherit from `Array` to use the provided methods.

Answer (score 1):

What you provide as an example is no different from an `Array`, so you could implement it as follows

```
class A < Array; end

a = A.new(10.times.map { |e| e })

#works great
a.new.each {}
a.new.select {|e| e > 3}
a.new.reject {|e| e > 3}
a.new.partition {|e| e > 3}
a.new.count
a.new.size
a.new.length
a.new.select! {|e| e > 3}
```

now of course this has no actual purpose as is, because it is just an `Array`, so depending on what **else** you want this class to do, you could add it as extra functionality.

eg

```
class A < Array
  def contains_the_answer_of_all_things?
    include? 42
  end
end
```

so that

```
a = A.new(10.times.map { |e| e })
a.contains_the_answer_of_all_things?
#=> false

b = A.new(100.times.map {|e| e })
b.contains_the_answer_of_all_things?
#=> true
```